# Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'J' using php

Tags: php, regex

I am using regular expression in php which is working fine. But, getting some warning like

```
Warning: preg_match_all(): Unknown modifier 'J'
```

My code is

```
$pattern = '/\b'.trim($keyword[$i]).'(s)??\b/i';
                    if(preg_match_all($pattern, substr($content,10), $matches)){
                        print_r($matches[0]);
                    }
```

the result of `print_r($keywords[$i])` is

```
Array
(
    [0] => best
    [1] =>  menu
    [2] =>  resturant
    [3] =>  resturants
    [4] =>  Food
    [5] =>  Dinner
    [6] =>  Lunch
)
```

For your reference.

Please help me in that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: give a print_r() in $keyword[$i]

Comment: I edited the question. please check now

Comment: `print_r($keywords[$i])` doesn't make sense with the output you've provided unless `$keywords` is a 2 dimensional array. To see the bigger picture, could you please "replicate" the `$keywords` in something like `$keywords = array("aaa", "bbb", "ccc");` and tell us what you're trying to accomplish in the end. Depending on the use-case `preg_grep()` could help you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use [`preg_quote()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-quote.php) preferably when you insert a word like that into a regular expression:

```
$pattern = '/\b'.preg_quote(trim($keyword[$i]), '/').'(s)??\b/i';
```

Comment: still getting the same warning after using your pattern

Comment: +1 for `preg_quote`... but -1 for double-escaping everything.  The only escape sequences that work in a single-quoted string are \\ and \'.  Anything else is unaffected; in particular, you don't need to double-backslash everything -- and that's part of the point of using single-quoted strings for REs.

Comment: @Gireesh I have made a small edit to my answer, please check.

Comment: I second the +1/-1. The double backslashes, they do nothing!

Comment: Cool, removing the -1 and leaving only the +1 now. ;)